# KnockoutJS model set sqlite table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can i have model in knockoutjs that gets its data from an sqlite table?.

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
var viewModel = {
    firstName: "Bert",
    lastName: "Bertington"

};

//viewModel->settable('table_name'); for instance.

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally missed the knockoutjs mapping plugin here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout entityspaces.js, there's a video you can watch, it supports full hierarchcial data models and will even generate your WCF JSON service, it supports REST API's as well.

A Javascript ORM (Data Access) Framework that uses Knockout

https://github.com/EntitySpaces/entityspaces.js#readme